# Discord.js messageReactionAdd ignore users

Tags: node.js, discord, bots, roles

I'm trying to add listening to my bot by adding roles to reactions. And it works, but only when the bot itself adds reactions. When any other user does this, the bot ignores it.
role-claim file where creat message for first message and creatind role - emoji for it:

```
const firstMessage = require('./first-message')


module.exports = (client) => {
    const channelId = '813819563703271484'

    const getEmoji = (emojiName) => client.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => emoji.name === emojiName)

    const emojis = {
        mercedes: 'Mercedes',
        ferrari: 'FERRARI',
        renault: 'RENAULT'
    }

    const reactions = []

    let  emojiText = 'Pick any team \n\n'
    for (const key in emojis) {
    const emoji = getEmoji(key)
    
    reactions.push(emoji)
    const role = emojis[key]
    emojiText += `${emoji} = ${role} \n` 

    }

    firstMessage(client, channelId, emojiText, reactions);

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) =>{
        console.log("add");
    })
    client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) =>{
        console.log("Remove");
    })
}
```

first-message create or edit first message and add reactions

```
    message.react(reactions[0])
    reactions.shift()
    if (reactions.length > 0) {
        setTimeout (() => addReactions(message, reactions), 750)
    }
}

module.exports = async (client, id, text, reactions = []) => {
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch(id)

    channel.messages.fetch().then((messages) =>{
        if (messages.size === 0){
            // 
            channel.send(text).then((message) => {
                addReactions(message, reactions)
            })
        } else {
            //
            for (const message of messages){
                message[1].edit(text)
                addReactions(message[1], reactions)   
            }
         
        }
    })
    
}
```

Index.js main bot file

```
const  rest  = require('@discordjs/rest');
const  Routes  = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const rolechannel = '813819563703271484';
const roleClaim = require('./role-claim')
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
client.login("||||||||||||||"); 
const config = require("./config.json");


client.on("ready", () => {
    client.user.setActivity("altV: Multiplayer on FreeZone", { type: "PLAYING" })
    console.log("1000-7");
    roleClaim(client);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need the `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intent for this to work.

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS] });
```